# What is Liquibase Producer and why it is used?

Tags: liquibase

I am getting to know about the Liquibase concept. But I couldn't find much information on LiquibaseProducer. Can anyone tell me what is LiquibaseProducer and why and how it is used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/puzzle/quickstart-javaee6-liquibase/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/puzzle/quickstart/database/LiquibaseProducer.java#L14-L18) the `LiquibaseProducer` is:

```
/**
 * The CDI Liquibase integration is a simple CDI extension that performs a
 * Liquibase update when the CDI container boots.
 *
 */
```

So if you incorporated this into your project, whenever your application started, it would

1. look at the liquibase changelog that was embedded in the application
2. look at the application configuration
3. connect to the application database
4. run `update` to make sure that the database schema was
   up-to-date with the changelog, potentially running any new change
   sets required.